# How is the value returned in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn rust and so far what I understood about returning values is that the value of the last statement inside a block is returned as long there is no semicolon after it.

In the following code the `x + 1`(no semicolon after) is returned and assigned to `y`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = 5;

    let y = {
        let x = 3;
        x + 1
    };

    println!("The value of y is: {}", y);
}
```

Output:

```
The value of y is: 4
```

But in the following piece of code how is `counter * 2` is returned although it has a semicolon after it.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut counter = 0;

    let result = loop {
        counter += 1;

        if counter == 10 {
            break counter * 2;
        }
    };

    println!("The result is {}", result);
}
```

Output:

```
The result is 20
```

Comment: The keyword `return` also works with a semicolon :) The last-expression-no-semicolon mechanism isn't the only way things are done, and as you've found, doesn't really work for loops.

Comment: `counter * 2` is "returned" as a result from the loop due to the `break` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the value of the last statement inside a block is returned as long there is no semicolon after it.

Technically the last value of a block is returned unless overridden. Outside of specific contexts where it's syntactically required, what `;` does is really suppress the value of the "current block" and substitute `()` for it, as you can see by trying to compile this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: u8 = { 0; };
}
```

The error will be [E0308 Mismatched Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0308): since `a` is typed explicitly, rustc expects the block's value to be an `u8` and complains that it's getting a `()`.

> But in the following piece of code how is counter * 2 is returned although it has a semicolon after it.

That's because there are two ways to *override* return values in specific contexts, at least currently:

- `return <expr>` will immediately exit from the current function with the result of `<expr>` as return value
- `break <expr>` will immediately exit from the current `loop` (or whichever matches the specified label if any) with the result of `<expr>` as "loop value", it only works with `loop` (not `while` or `for`) because the loop has to be executed at least once for this to work

Answer (score 1):

[In the 2018 eddition, loops can be expressions and thus return a value.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/control-flow/loops-can-break-with-a-value.html) This is achieved using the `break <value>;` syntax. Note that this works  for `loop` loops only and does not work for `while` or `for` loops.